# Weird issue with cftextarea/cfwindow

Tags: coldfusion, internet-explorer-8, rich-text-editor

A while ago, I worked on an application where a manager can approve/deny xxx applications. When some body selects an action from a drop down, it opens a `cfwindow` and loads `cftextarea richtext="yes"` in there, so that they could enter reasons for approval/denial.

Now the culprit is that in production, the fckEditor has a ton of funky chars in IE8. Same thing won't happen in FireFox. Also, the IE8 does not show the same stuff in dev.

I have looked at the scripts in `/cf_admin/CFIDE/scripts/ajax/FCKeditor`, they are all the same.

Since this wasn't an issue before, I am not sure where to look at. Something got updated on the server which probably causes this problem. Does anybody know what could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the vp put the header `X-UA-Compatible: IE=IE7` in IIS to force IE8 emulate IE7. When I made them change this to `X-UA-Compatible: IE=EmulateIE7`, everything started to work perfectly again. For more details see [Introducing IE=EmulateIE7](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2008/06/10/introducing-ieemulateie7/).

Hope it helps others. Thanks.